# Total number of NEAR token staked in NEAR Blockchain

Tags: nearprotocol, staking

I need to get the total number of NEAR token staked in NEAR Blockchain programmatically, like it is shown in the NEAR explorer(https://explorer.near.org/nodes/validators).
[Total Staked in NEAR Blockchain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKZwD.png)

NEAR provides JSON RPC API(https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/setup) to get some of the details by hitting respective RPC endpoints.
For example, I am able to get the total number of NEAR token staked in a staking pool using below RPC constructs.

```
endpoint URL: https://rpc.mainnet.near.org
Header = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
Body:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "query",
  "params": {
    "request_type": "call_function",
    "finality": "final",
    "account_id": "staking pool id",
    "method_name": "get_total_staked_balance",
    "args_base64": '{"account_id": “staking account id”}’ in base64 encoding
  }
}
```

But there is no similar details available to get Total NEAR Staked in NEAR Blockchain.
Would appreciate if someone could help me in this. Thanks.

Went through NEAR official API documentation(https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/setup), NEAR explorer codebase(https://github.com/near/near-explorer), NEAR core-contracts codebase(https://github.com/near/core-contracts)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `EXPERIMENTAL_validators_ordered`:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "dontcare",
  "method": "EXPERIMENTAL_validators_ordered",
  "params": ["JD8o38fkxG34QsBS4ZwT8hieehNUeJMAPCgKGk6xnbuf"]
}'
```

This will return a list with all validators and their stake:

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
        {
            "account_id": "figment.poolv1.near",
            "public_key": "ed25519:7RjyY1bRKDqkshbKZtgpQdwsdxou8j9my8g1hPKZ9ngM",
            "stake": "32093438089641651528322513598448",
            "validator_stake_struct_version": "V1"
        },
        {
            "account_id": "astro-stakers.poolv1.near",
            "public_key": "ed25519:2nPSBCzjqikgwrqUMcuEVReJhmkC91eqJGPGqH9sZc28",
            "stake": "25153541134999320232972613031893",
            "validator_stake_struct_version": "V1"
        },
        {
            "account_id": "bzam6yjpnfnxsdmjf6pw.poolv1.near",
            "public_key": "ed25519:2ZJqaaCAisK4u8E2i611zFfvNmrvevovnU3M7SpGHkLY",
            "stake": "23349905747168797648450246349622",
            "validator_stake_struct_version": "V1"
        },
        ...
   ]
}
```

---

You can also use [near-cli](https://github.com/near/near-cli): `near validators current`

Comment: Thanks @Marcelo Fornet. By the way, what you are sending in params?

Comment: The hash of a NEAR block. You can use the latest produced hash to have an up to date information.